# rx.Subscriber entity cannot be reused after unsubscribe?

Tags: android, rx-java

I've got construct like this (RxJava 1.3.x):

```
view().filter(view -> view != null).subscribe(subscriber);
```

Here is also definition of view(). It actively emits `View` entities.

```
public Observable<View> view() {
    return views;
}
```

Question: why trivial implementation of `rx.Subscriber` onNext (and further passing into subscribe) works (that is, onNext is being called) but this one does not:

```
subscriber.unsubscribe();
view().filter(view -> view != null).subscribe(subscriber);
```

Comment: look at `SubscriptionList::unsubscribe` - docs : Unsubscribe from all of the subscriptions in the list, which stops the receipt of notifications on the associated {@code Subscriber}.  It seems quite self explanatory, once called you cannot reuse the `Subscriber`

Comment: The 1.x Subscriber is stateful and once you unsubscribe it, it will immediately unsubscribe from any future use. You have to create a fresh instance or use an instance of the `rx.Observer` interface.

Comment: Ok once again reviewed code of rx.Subscriber. You guys are right, I cannot implement what I want with rx.Subscriber. Whoever of you bother to post your comments as answer first, I'll accept.

Comment: @akarnokd is a major contributor to reactive extensions for Java (RxJava project https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava  ) - you should trust his comments, I have merely quoted the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1.x `Subscriber` is stateful and once you unsubscribe it, it will immediately unsubscribe from any future use. You have to create a fresh instance or use an instance of the `rx.Observer` interface.

```
// as fields for example

Subscription subscripion;
Observer<View> observer = new Observer<View>() {
     @Override public void onNext(View t) { }
     @Override public void onError(Throwable t) { }
     @Override public void onCompleted() { }
});

// ...

if (subscription != null) subscription.unsubscribe();

subscription = view().filter(view -> view != null).subscribe(observer);
```